# PayPal: an error occurred in secure channel support

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

I'm trying to use the PayPal Express sandbox (which I have to over 5+ years) and all of a sudden, I'm getting this error.  I'm running the latest Chrome on a Windows 2012 server that's up to date.  It's happening on the first call to PP using SetExpressCheckout.  Where do I start looking for the cause?

Answer (score 1):

After a week of trying to get help from PayPal support, I accidentally came across this link: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ssl-security-update that let me to the fix.  Support never mentioned it.

The key is to actively use TLS 1.2 in your code. It's not enough to just have your server hardened (we were showing an "A" rating on SSLlabs.com).  I put the following immediately before the instantiation of WebClient:

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Connected to PayPal without a problem after that.